# How to select only physical device in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, api, webrtc

does someone know how to select only physical devices in webrtc?

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ this is giving all devices possible.

it seems like it also returns virtual ones.

many thanks

Comment: its looks like you cant filter InputDeviceInfo's by physical or not, because we dont have usefull property for it

Comment: thank you tried to solve it with deviceInfo.kind and deviceInfo.label

Comment: you can post answer's to your own question